# I want to execute jenkins pipeline as a administrator

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to execute jenkins pipeline as a administrator
or
I want to execute pipeline with specific cmd.exe.lnk that I setup 'run as administrator' option.
Also, When I tried to build below windows command, I can't watch the build log on console output.

```
[ windows command sample ]
- start (PATH)\cmd.exe.lnk /k "cd (PATH)\mvn clean package"
```

And,
I already tried to build with bat file that setup 'run as administrator' option.
but It was also just finished as 'success' but nothing to happen for me.

Please, let me know how should I do in this situation.

Comment: When you say "nothing to happen for me", does it mean that the script you want to run did not run?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson Yes, just in pipeline console. when I build with that command on local build server, another cmd windows open and then build is started there. but nothing to happen on pipeline console output.